# Plotting GPS plot without uploading data

Tags: javascript, gps

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but I'm wondering if its possible to plot a GPS dataset without uploading the data first to CartoDB.

I've been analysing some data by uploading the postcode data to CartoDB and then using Javascript to control the mapping via the CSS and SQLApi which is really good. I can't however, figure out how to do this with several GPS plots, as I'd like to show a breadcrumb trail from data I have locally.